# How to check user has permission special node

Tags: 8, users

I following topic https://atendesigngroup.com/blog/custom-permissions-node-access-grants-drupal-8-and-drupal-7 to create custom permissions for node. It's working ok. Example I can edited node 1 with url: example.com/node/1/edit/. I wan't check user have permission edit node by code eg:

```
node_access('view', $node);
```

and Drupal 8

```
$node = Node::load(1);
$account = User::load(1);
$check = $node->access('edit', $account);
```

But It don't working. So how can check permission of special node?

Comment: See \Drupal\node\NodeAccessControlHandler::access for how the access check is actually doing it.

Comment: The operations are view, update, delete (and create but usually don't have an entity yet then), not edit. But how do you know it's working when it is apparently not?

Answer (score 1):

Just tested this and `$node->access('update');` works for me. I let the optional $account parameter out so that it would check the currently logged in user.

The only difference was that I loaded my node with:

```
\Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
```

To just use `Node::load($nid);` Make sure to include:

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
```

at the top of your file.

Answer (score 0):

As Rubix05 mentions, the issue is that you are testing "edit" access when you should be testing "update" access.

```
$node = Node::load(1);
$account = User::load(1);
$check = $node->access('update', $account);
```